# Clean specific data in next build only once

Tags: android, gradle, build

I need to clean storage list with saved defect dialogs only once, when users will update my app to the new version (on google play and crashlytics).

What is the best way to realize it?

Answer (score 0):

Have `versionCode` in the app itself.. oh wait, it's already there.

When app starts on the device, check the storage, if there is some fixed file/data with this versionCode (or store it into SharedPreferences).

If not, clear the storage and create the fixed mark with current versionCode.

Next time you will find this mark, and skip storage clean.